# TDS Custom Post Deploy Action > Could not create type ''. Type.GetType() returned null

Tags: tds

**Sitecore**: 9.0.2 PaaS

**TDS**: 5.7.0.21

For a while (years) we have leveraged custom Post Deploy Actions in TDS but have recently run into an issue where TDS appears unable to retrieve our custom actions.

### Error (full extent of what is visible)

```
2019-04-26T16:16:16  PID[9124] Information 5272 16:16:16 INFO  4/26/2019-4:16:16 PM: Executing post deploy action My.Foundation.TDS.PostDeploy.PublishDeployedItemsWithPublishingQueue,My.Foundation.TDS with parameter 'Internet'
2019-04-26T16:16:16  PID[9124] Information 5272 16:16:16 INFO  4/26/2019-4:16:16 PM: Could not create type ''. Type.GetType() returned null.
```

It appears to try and pull all custom Validators by type (presumably IPostDeployAction), but is unable to get a handle on our action.

The Post Deploy Action is verbatim from this post: https://www.geekhive.com/buzz/post/2017/10/tds-post-deploy-action-publish-items-via-publishing-queue/

I reviewed other examples from https://www.teamdevelopmentforsitecore.com/Post-Deploy-Scripts and all follow the same format.

The version of `HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.PackageInstallPostProcessor.dll` we are referencing locally is the same instance used during deployment.

*Note: I am aware that TDS 5.8 can eliminate this issue, however, there is an ongoing issue where it disrespects GitDeltaDeploy (discussion in slack recently) so I'm hesitant to upgrade.*

Comment: I am currently having the same issue as mentioned here. Were you able to resolve it? if so, can you please share?

Comment: I am no longer associated with this issue, and never solved it at the time.